# Can javascript code, in a page returned by ajax, call a function that was in a js file of the original page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have something similar to this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Test</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="searchResults" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The searchResults div will get populated by a jQuery .load(). The result that is returned into the div has javascript to be executed. This much works fine.

Now I need some of the javascript that gets returned into searchResults to call a function in page.js. This currently does not work. Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

I sort of found the problem. In page.js the function I am trying to call is inside a $(document).ready statement. If declare the function outside of the document ready it works. Anyone care to explain to me why this is and is there a way to leave it in the document ready area?

Comment: i think it is possible but it depends on some factors. maybe you could add the error you are receiving, an example of what gets inserted into searchResults, and a minimal page.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone care to explain to me why this is and is there a way to leave it in the document ready area?

It is not is the same scope as the other function. You know what I mean? It is hidden because it is inside another function (the document ready function). It is the same with a variable. If you declare a local variable inside a function, some code outside the function can't just directly reference that variable that is inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

When you load into `$('#searchResults')` the `document.ready()` was already called so anything wrapped in those tags will **not** be done.

Comment: I understand how the code in the document.ready() won't be called a second time but shouldn't the function which was declared the first time still be available for calling??

Comment: functions should **not** be wrapped in `document.ready` only wrap select cases (`$('select').something()`) or else it wont be available to the whole scope. i have had the same problem before.